# Doubts about adding matplotlib graphs to a webpage

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, raspberry-pi, mpld3

So, I'm learning how to use matplotlib and stumbled into MPLD3 as the most used way to get these plots in a webpage. However, MPLD3 doesn't support tick formatting and that's something critical for the project I'm in right now. I'd like to know if there is another way to add a matplotlib graph to a webpage while keeping the tick formatting and also having tooltips to display data on hover.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For a web application I would consider [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/).  You can output html with interactive charts or run another backend server.  If you go to the ipython notebook tutorial [section 10](https://hub.mybinder.org/user/bokeh-bokeh-notebooks-2f5q71k0/notebooks/tutorial/10%20-%20Exporting%20and%20Embedding.ipynb) has demos for embedding.

Alternatively you can just save images from matplotlib and use them as static assets in your page.